# Xcode - Storyboard compilation failed

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, storyboard, interface-builder

On Running the application on iPhone, Build got failed with the following error on compiling Root.Storyboard. But this failure not happening overtime. This happens randomly.

```
14:59:57 2016-08-02 14:59:45.730 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[3825:17239088] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{objective 0x7fa3cd88fe70: <1:5.34034> + <1:0.0320392>*0x7fa3cbef2f20:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 6394} + <1:-0.0320392>*0x7fa3cbef2f20:UISV-fill-proportionally.posErrorMarker{id: 6393} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd865df0:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 5980} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd86a290:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 5978} + <1:1>*0x7fa3cd86f760:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 5717} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd899a00:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 5981} + <1:-1.94859>*0x7fa3cd89bc40:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 5936} + <1:1.94859>*0x7fa3cd89bc40:UISV-fill-proportionally.posErrorMarker{id: 5935} + <1:0.0333092>*0x7fa3cd8a63e0:UISV-fill-equally.marker{id: 5985} + <1:0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd8a7d30:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 6008} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd8ab0e0:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 6009} + <1:1.94859>*0x7fa3cd8abc30.negError{id: 5906} + <1:0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd8c6a10:UISV-canvas-connection.marker{id: 5976} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd8de630:UISV-fill-equally.marker{id: 5984} + <1:-0.0166546>*0x7fa3cd8eb6f0:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 6040} + <1:1>*0x7fa3cdd1b550.marker{id: 6266}}: internal error.  Setting empty vector for variable 0x7fa3cd8701b0.negError{id: 5693}.'
14:59:57 *** First throw call stack:
14:59:57 (
14:59:57    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112bc7d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
14:59:57    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112639deb objc_exception_throw + 48
14:59:57    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112bc7cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
14:59:57    3   Foundation                          0x000000011220dacc -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression setPriorityVector:forKnownAbsentVariable:] + 76
14:59:57    4   Foundation                          0x00000001123b0c44 __128-[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:]_block_invoke + 297
14:59:57    5   Foundation                          0x000000011220a6bf -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariablesAndCoefficients:] + 350
14:59:57    6   Foundation                          0x00000001123b0b04 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:] + 369
14:59:57    7   Foundation                          0x000000011220b7ee -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 633
14:59:57    8   Foundation                          0x000000011220e789 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 330
14:59:57    9   Foundation                          0x000000011220c082 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 146
14:59:57    10  Foundation                          0x00000001123acacf -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 158
14:59:57    11  Foundation                          0x000000011220bc0f -[NSISEngine optimize] + 46
14:59:57    12  Foundation                          0x000000011220c42d -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 245
14:59:57    13  UIKit                               0x00000001103b9adb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
14:59:57    14  UIKit                               0x00000001103ba61e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 254
14:59:57    15  UIKit                               0x00000001103aac47 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 108
14:59:57    16  UIKit                               0x00000001103bb333 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 272
14:59:57    17  UIKit                               0x000000010fb6fa96 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 159
14:59:57    18  UIKit                               0x000000010fb4c6f6 -[UIWindow layoutSubviews] + 43
14:59:57    19  UIKit                               0x000000010fb7f980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
14:59:57    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000011209dc00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
14:59:57    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000011209208e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
14:59:57    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112091f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
14:59:57    23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001120863c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
14:59:57    24  QuartzCore                          0x00000001120b4086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
14:59:57    25  QuartzCore                          0x00000001120b47f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
14:59:57    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112aecc37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
14:59:57    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112aecba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
14:59:57    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112ae211c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
14:59:57    29  Foundation                          0x0000000112222a31 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
14:59:57    30  IBFoundation                        0x0000000111e8330f -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 429
14:59:57    31  IBFoundation                        0x0000000111e834ee -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 117
14:59:57    32  IBFoundation                        0x0000000111e83fea +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1177
14:59:57    33  Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool  0x000000010f96abe7 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool + 3047
14:59:57    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001169ab92d start + 1
14:59:57 )
14:59:57 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
14:59:58 Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Thanks in advance.